# How do you tell whether the user initiated onTaskRemoved or the system did?

Tags: android, foreground-service

My goal is for the user to be able to swipe an app away and shut down a foreground service. I do this by overriding onTaskRemoved. This works as expected, and I shut down my service from the method, but now there is the issue of the system shutting down the foreground service using onTaskRemoved.

Forget what setting I used, but my app is listed as exempt in the standby apps.

What can I do to stop the system from shutting down my foreground service?

I do what the developers guide says and more.

```
        Intent intentServiceMain = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ServiceMain.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(intentServiceMain);
        } else {
            startService(intentServiceMain);
        }
```

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setUpNotificationBuilder();
            notification = notificationCompatBuilder.build();
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID.hashCode(), notification);
            return START_STICKY;
    }
```

```
    private void setUpNotificationBuilder() {
        notificationCompatBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music_note_black_48dp)
                .setContentTitle(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
        remoteViewsNotificationLayout =
                new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.pane_notification);
        notificationCompatBuilder.setCustomContentView(remoteViewsNotificationLayout);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityMain.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notificationCompatBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, importance);
            String description = "Service";
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"system shutting down the foreground service using onTaskRemoved"_ Any evidence of that statement? [When can onTaskRemoved() be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40072391/3290339) refers to the documentation that states: _"This is called if the service is currently running and the user has removed a task"_

Comment: Huh, I went from charging to file transfer in settings when onTaskRemoved was called; it was printed to logcat. Also there were 2 times when the phone was under load that the service was killed. I do not have log info on what happened those times though.

Comment: That did not stop the Service when I tried it again.

Comment: The things might have changed over the years :)